# Design Ecommerce Microservices

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices

I am designing an Ecommerce using micro services architecture. Suppose that I have two context a product catalog, inventory and pricing.
It's seems clear to me that they have a clear responsibility. But to serve the show case (the product list) I need to make a request for the product catalog, get a list of ID's and then use it to query the Inventory micro services to check inventory status ( in stock or stockout). Besides that I need to make a request to Pricing to get the price of each product.

So basically to serve a fundamental feature makes me execute three requests (like a join) in three micro services. I have been reading about micro services architecture and when you are dealing with many "joins" it's possible that the these contexts should be a single one. But, IMO it seems clear to me that each context has a different set of responsibilities.

The other option is to create a "search" micro service that aggregate all these information (product + pricing + inventory). We can use a domain event to notify "search" microsecond that something has changed. So we can resolve show case with a single request. This look like a CQRS.

The question is...

Is there a correct approach?

Which one is better ? Trade-offs?

Comment: Probably this will answer your question in more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54676222/1235935

Answer (score 0):

### Update on 14-Feb-2019

Probably this will answer your question in more detail https://stackoverflow.com/a/54676222/1235935

---

I think the right approach here is to use Event Sourcing to pre-aggregate the show case data with product description, inventory and price. A separate microservice is probably not needed. This pre-aggregated data (a.k.a. materialized view) can be stored in the same microservice that handles the user request to display products (probably the order creation service).

The events could be generated by log-based Change Data Capture (CDC) from the DB of the product, inventory and pricing services and writing them to their respective topics in a log structured streaming platform (e.g. Kafka or AWS Kinesis) as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54527066/1235935). This will also ensure "read your own write" guarantees in product, inventory and pricing services

Answer (score 0):

you can try to include some information from different domain contexts to other domain context

so you product catalog domain will contain #of items , price from inventory and pricing domains.

This will be a read only (value objects)and should be updated by events from inventory and pricing domains .

in your use case the trusted source of truth will be carried in inventory domain so if any synchronization failure happen still the inventory will reject any order because of availability .

Answer (score 0):

in your case i think its better to create a separate search microservice to aggregate the data from all of them as search is mostly always from multiple domain areas like product , inventory and ....

and you can use events from other microservice (Event Sorucing) to populate the data in search.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you need is to show in a view info coming from different microservices (contexts).

You can use ViewModel Composition technic, where an infraestructure component (a request handler) intercepts the http request and allows microservices to participate in the response, looking for a microservice who says "hey, I have that info" (Inventory has the info about stock, Pricing about price, and so on). This infraestructure component compose a dynamic viewmodel on the fly, with the info coming from differect microservices.

I've never implemented it, but look at this video explaining it, from minute 17:35 to 21:00

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkzvQSuYd5I

Hope it helps.