# Mechanisms for response aggregation in event sourcing based microservices

Tags: microservices, event-sourcing

When it comes to implementing event sourcing based microservices, one of the main concerns that we've come across is aggregating data for responses. For an example we may have two entities like school and student. One microservice may be responsible for handling school related business logic while another may handle students.

Now if someone makes a query through a REST endpoint and ask for a particular student and they might expect both school and student details, then the only known ways for me are the following.

1. Use something like service chaining. An example would be an Api-Gateway aggregating a response after making couple of requests to couple of microservices.
2. Having everything replicated throughout all services. Essentially, data would be duplicated.
3. Having services calling each other for those extra bit of information. This solution works but hard to scale and goes against basic idea of using event sourcing.

My question is that what other ways are there to do this ?

Comment: "Essentially, data would be duplicated"  Once upon a time, that was called caching.  It wasn't regarded as a bad thing.

Comment: You may have to create materialized view based on your events to query the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/54676222/1235935

Answer (score 0):

A better approach can be to create a separate reporting/search service, that aggregates the data from both services. For example implemented using ElasticSearch or SOLR.This now allows the users to do search and queries across multiple services and aggregates.

Sure, it will be eventually consistent, but I doubt that is s a problem. This gives a better separation of concerns and you get a nice search experience for your users at the same time.